# Smooth confidence intervals on Kaplan Meier

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval

I'm attempting to plot Kaplan-Meier curves using the following [tutorial](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/survminer-r-package-survival-data-analysis-and-visualization) specifically the lines:

```
require("survival")
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
ggsurvplot(fit, linetype = "strata", conf.int = TRUE, pval = TRUE, palette = "Dark2")
```

I plotted the image from my computer on the right, the plot from the tutorial is on the left:[image]

While it's subtle, the shape of the confidence intervals in my plot is very jagged while the tutorials is quite smooth. How can I get the "smooth" look?

I'm using R version 3.4.1

Comment: There were probably just many more observations in the tutorial data. The usual confidence interval calculation only changes at observed points. KM CIs aren't smooth; they are step functions.

Comment: I'm using the same "lung" dataset as the tutorial. Interestingly, I am facing this problem because I used to have "smooth" CIs on a different dataset but after swapping computers and needing to rewrite my analysis script, they are now "choppy" (dataset is as before).

Comment: Are you using different versions of the `survival` package on different versions of R?

Answer (score 0):

After reverting back to older versions of Survival (2.38-3), Survminer (0.2.0), and ggplot2 (2.0.0), I was able to recreate the example plot with "smooth" CIs.